# One-dimension random walk expected exit time

Tags: expected-value, random-walk

There is a pawn in $x=0$ at $t=0$. At $t'=t+1$ the pawn moves to $x+1$ or $x-1$ with probabilities $p$, $1-p$.
What is the mean time to escape from the boundaries $-k$, $+n$, where $k,n\in \mathbb N$, $k,n>0$ ?
I know the answer is $kn$ for $p=\frac12$, I would like to know how to prove it and how to find and prove the answer for arbitrary $p\in (0,1)$.
Thank you.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The answer is some function of $k$, $n$ (integer arguments), $p$ (real parameter): $T(k,n;p)$. One can write recurrence equation: $T(k,n;p)=1+p T(k+1,n-1;p)+(1-p) T(k-1,n+1;p)$ for $k,n>0$, $T(0,n;p)=0$, $T(k,0;p)=0$. Then one can solve this recurrence equation at constant $p$.

Comment: Many thanks, @IvanKaznacheyeu, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Solving the functional equation I have $$E=\dfrac{k\,p^{n+k}+n\,q^{n+k}-(n+k)\,p^kq^n}{(p-q)(p^{n+k}-q^{n+k})}$$where $q=1-p$.
The formula has no meaning for $p=q=\frac12$ but we have $$\lim_{p\to\frac12}E=kn$$as it should be.